# Will Actix handle HTTP/2 websocket upgrade automatically if SSL supplied?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I was wondering if it's possible in Actix to upgrade an HTTP/2 and use websocket with binary data exchange. I'm currently following the example provided here: https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/websocket/src/main.rs

According to the documentation on: https://github.com/actix/actix-website/blob/master/content/docs/http2.md it claims: `actix-web automatically upgrades connections to HTTP/2.0 if possible.`

Basically if I use the example above (adding the necessary SSL details) and make a request from my client as an HTTP/2 websocket request, will this source automatically act as HTTP/2 or just use a basic websocket?

Are there any gotchas here I should be aware of or am I getting this completely wrong?